# PostgreSQL creating fields that both fields cannot repeat

Tags: postgresql, constraints

Given table, would you please us how to set up the unique constraint so that first_name and last_name are not allowed to type the same field?

```
CREATE TABLE app_user (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   first_name VARCHAR (50),
   last_name VARCHAR (50),
   email VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE
);


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_firstname_last_name_id ON app_test.app_user(first_name text_ops,last_name text_ops);
```

I have created unique constraint including (first_name, last_name) but to no avail.

If first_name is 'Chan'  , last_name is 'Mandy' , the database triggers allows this record to be updated

If first_name is 'Chan'  , last_name is 'Chan' , the database triggers does not allow this record to be updated

As for insert first time, the constraint check can be ignored

Comment: Question Edited . It is the table user

Comment: user is a reserved word(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: no longer user now . It is app_user

Comment: The code is fine.

Comment: Edited, Here is the case

Answer (score 1):

Use a [check constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) if you want the two columns not to contain the same values, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE app_user (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   first_name VARCHAR (50),
   last_name VARCHAR (50),
   email VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE,
   CHECK(first_name <> last_name)
);

insert into app_user (first_name, last_name)
values('Adam', 'Adam');

ERROR:  new row for relation "app_user" violates check constraint "app_user_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, Adam, Adam, null).
```

Comment: How can we apply check only if the user record is UPDATE instead of INSERT?

Comment: The check constraint applies to the table, not to statements. It works both when inserting and updating rows.

Answer (score 0):

Check constraints apply to all table DML operation (well Insert and Update) enteries. So what you want cannot be done with constraints. You can accomplish it with trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE app_user (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   first_name VARCHAR (50),
   last_name VARCHAR (50),
   email VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE
); 

create or replace function reject_same_name()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    if old.first_name = old.last_name then
       raise exception 'Cannot update row when first name and last name are the same.';
    end if;
    return new;
end ;
$$;

insert into app_user (first_name, last_name)
values('Adam', 'Adam');
-- 1 row 

insert into app_user (first_name, last_name)
values ('Sam','Henery');
-- 1 row 
select * from app_user;

update app_user
   set email = first_name || '.' || last_name || '@mydb.com' 
 where first_name = 'Sam'; 
-- 1 row updated

update app_user
   set email = first_name || '.' || last_name || '@mydb.com' 
 where first_name = 'Adam';  -- Is this really what we want??
********** Error **********

ERROR: Cannot update row when first name and last name are the same.
SQL state: P0001
```

So far so good? But what happens when we realize an mistake was made: Like the last name was inserted incorrectly so we correct to:

```
update app_user set last_name = 'Smith' 
  where last_name = 'Adam';
```

So that trigger function may need lots of work deciding the business rule as to what can and what cannot be updated and when.  Triggers are really a bad ways to enforce business rules.